# skin for iPod touch 4G that works with universal dock

Tags: ipod-touch, accessories

I am looking for a thin/tight yet robust rubberish/silicon skin for my latest iPod touch 4G. It should have a single black or dark gray color and not not have any pimples or ripples.

Simply put: as unobstrusive and robust as possible.

Also the iPod touch still should fit into the apple universal dock.

Wich skin would you suggest?

If you can't come up with one that works with the dock, could you at least suggest a general good skin (thin, tight, robust). I have tried the "COOL BANANAS Value Pack for iPod Touch 4G" and it is really not worth its money.

Answer (score 1):

rather than find a skin that fits into the universal dock, you should find a skin you like and then change the piece of plasic that changes the size of teh dock connecton to one suitable for your iPod Touch and teh skin/case.